# Which defferences "Seq" with "seq" ?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm worried when don't know when you can use "Seq" , "seq" . Can you tell me which defferences are ?

This's my code . Why dont't use "seq" ?

```
 let s = ResizeArray<float>()
 s.Add(1.1)
 s.Add(2.2)
 s.Add(3.3)
 s.Add(4.4)
 s |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn("%f") x )
```

Comment: [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences)

Answer (score 8):

`Seq` is a module that contains functions that work with `seq` values:

```
Seq.map string [ 1; 2 ]
Seq.sum [ 1; 2 ]
```

---

`seq` is a type name:

```
let f1 (xs : seq<int>) = ()
let f2 (xs : int seq) = ()
```

---

`seq` is also a function that converts something like a list into the type `seq`:

```
seq [ 1; 2 ]
```

---

`seq { ... }` is a [computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions):

```
seq { yield 1; yield 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the uppercase Seq in all cases except in type annotation. 
For example:

```
let (x:seq<int>) = 
    [1..10]
    |> Seq.map (fun t -> t + 1)
```

Edit: Please refer to recommended answer, as my answer is incomplete.

Comment: And "seq" ? When can you use its ?

Comment: @AIRO2001 `seq` it's just an alias for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, so `type seq<'T> = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>`