# What's the real type of seq<T>?

Tags: f#

*seq* is an alias of the *IEnumerable* interface, then you can **create objects which implements *IEnumerable*** and use its methods, for example:

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and use the IEnumerable methods:

```
Where, Max, etc.
```

But you must instance an object that implements *IEnumerable*.

But... in F# you can create a sequence like:

```
let list = seq { for i in 1..5 -> i }
```

And Visual Studio says you list has the *seq* type. This is impossible, ***seq* is an interface (*IEnumerable*)** and you can't create an instance of an interface.

So, what's the magic inside *seq*?

**Using GetType in FSI:**

```
let goingToSee = seq { for i in 1..5 -> i }
goingToSee.GetType();;
val goingToSee : seq<int>
val it : System.Type = FSI_0010+goingToSee@12
```

Comment: What does `list.GetType()` tell you?

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Very strange. I've updated the post.

Comment: I don't know F# compiler internals, but I'd speculate that the compiler creates a new type called `FSI_0010+goingToSee@12` which implements `IEnumerable<int>`. Its `GetEnumerator` method would return a custom `IEnumerator<int>` which would contain the logic to lazily build sequences based on the `seq { ... }` body in your code. This would make it different from custom computation expression builders which have to manipulate a specific but common representation of the type... Maybe I'm completely wrong, someone probably knows more, let's wait if someone answers before I post this as an answer

Comment: But for most practical purposes, the concrete implementation should not matter. It's a lazy sequence which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and behaves as you would expect. It's similar to C#/LINQ methods like `Enumerable.Range(1,5)` - it gives you *some* `IEnumerable<int>`, your code should not care what its concrete type is as long as it behaves according to contract

Comment: Not f# guy but you can look over https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs which may be helpful to inspect internals.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530162/) answers your question very well. The question itself is not an exact duplicate, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `seq { .. }` expression in F# is more similar to iterator methods in C# (written using the `yield` keyword) than to collection initializers. Similarly to the C# compiler handling of iterators, F# compiler turns the `seq { .. }` expression into a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

The compiled class inherits from `GeneratedSequenceBase` (see the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seqcore.fs#L356)) and puts code generated based on what you wrote in the sequence expression. It is compiled as a state machine, so the code looks a bit ugly, but if you look at it using ILSpy, it looks something like this:

```
internal sealed class list@6 : GeneratedSequenceBase<int> {
  public override int GenerateNext(ref IEnumerable<int> next) {
      switch (this.pc) {
          case 1: goto IL_82;
          case 2: this.i = 0; break;
          case 3: goto IL_A3;
          default: {
              this.@enum = Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32(1, 1, 5).GetEnumerator();
              this.pc = 1;
              break; }
    }
      if (this.@enum.MoveNext()) {
          this.i = this.@enum.Current;
          this.pc = 2;
          this.current = this.i;
          return 1;
      }
      IL_82:
        this.pc = 3;
        LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.Dispose<IEnumerator<int>>(this.@enum);
      this.@enum = null;
        this.pc = 3;
      IL_A3:
        this.current = 0;
        return 0;
  }
}
```

I will not try to decode this, but I think `pc` keeps the state of the state machine. Depending on this, it either initializes the iterator, moves to the next state, or disposes of any resources that might be used.

It's also worth noting that the 6 in the name `list@6` is the line number from where this generated class comes from.