# Why F# seq starts with small letter?

Tags: f#, sequence, naming

I am new to F# and I noticed that all other collection types start with a capital letter except for sequences. Is this because the `seq` is actually merely an alias for IEnumerable and not an actual new F# type like the other ones?

Thank you.

Comment: Thx @BentTranberg for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#, a sequence can expressed via the built in computation expression named "seq". Computation Expressions are by convention lower case. You can define your own computation expressions in upper case, but convention is lower case.

*seq* - when used as a computation expression - is not an alias for IEnumerable, but seq will create an IEnumerable.

But there are more meanings of seq as clarified in the comments.

Comment: Hi @cityid. Thx for the answer. Do other F# collection types have similar computation expressions?

Comment: no. but there is an analogon to seq { yield 1 } for lists: [ yield 1 ] so in the list case you just use brackets.

Comment: Actually, the type `seq` *is* an alias for `IEnumerable`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530162/609639

Comment: oh yes, seq is many things, right! good link

Comment: @BentTranberg sure it does. and "seq" starts with lowercase.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Thx for clarifying things. Do all alias types start with a small letter or there is something special about seq type?

Comment: @geeko There are also several other type aliases in the F# core library that are lower case `array`, `list` etc. I think these existed partly for compatibility with OCaml. Anyone can define a type alias or type in F# code using lower or upper case (e.g. `type blah = int`). The casing tends to follow certain conventions but it's not functionally important.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Thx again. What are these naming conventions for type aliases?